# circle becomes an oval after saving

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop

Using ArcGIS Desktop v10 i am editing a "tank" layer.

It is selected as the only editable layer

It has three features all of which have circle as the diagrammatic property.

I use the circle tool and construct a new circle.

It draws nicely.

Then I save edit

Then I stop editing the layer.

Visually it turns into an oval!

Thoughts?

[image: circle after adding feature to layer]

[image: the oval appears after saving and exit editing]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? Also, is it still an oval when exporting/printing? If you haven't already, try restarting Arcmap, that solves the majority of all problems...

Comment: Please measure the distances from the center in south and west direction to check, if the projection is OK and this is just a vizualization error.

Also you can try to open the edited layer in another software (QGIS) and see, if the distortion is also present.

Answer (score 6):

I would say, that perhaps you are using Coordinate system, which distorts lengths/angles. Also, what are the units of your project? Are they metric? If you use WGS84 (for example), than circle with radius 1 degree may not look as a circle.

Basically: Measure the lengths in metric units (metres) in different directions and compare, if they are truly different

Comment: Quick test for whether the problem is unprojected data: does the problem get worse as you move away from the equator?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue editing a layer in WGS 1984. I created a new shapefile without a defined projection and the distortion did not occur after I saved the edits. Looks like Zbynek was correct, it is a projection issue. Try projecting the layer into what your mxd is projected in and maybe redrawing the circle.